# Separate each letter of a text to its own layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, layers, animation, adobe-after-effects

I feel like there is a simple solution but I can't find it basically what the title says. **I select the text and select release to layers (sequence) and nothing happens or just creates a new layer inside it and moves the whole text in there.** I can't ungroup them its greyed out as well.

[image]
Reason: want to separate it so I can then import it to After Affects and animate the logo/text.
If that's possible, lastly is there a way I can separate the text with a Arc Lower Warp applied keep the same effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate, although I don't know if PS and IL behave identically: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/737/how-do-i-break-apart-text-in-photoshop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line of text is seen as **one** object in Illustrator.

If you want each character as a separate object, you need to create separate text objects for *each* character.

`Type > Create Outlines` will convert the text object to vector shapes, then each shape can be manipulated.

`Object > Expand` will convert text in an envelope to vector shapes, which can then be manipulated individually.

Comment: Then ungroup and release layers to layers (sequence). Your a god thank you.

Comment: *Release to Layers* was the step I was missing. I couldn't figure out how to separate a dot from an "i"!

Answer (score 1):

Now to do this with a lower Arc effect all we need to do is **create outline** and **expand appearance** instead of just expand then ungroup and release sequence to layers. For anyone wondering how to do it with the effect.